# Android create static ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, static

im trying to remove values from an arrayList im my android app, but they keep re-appearing.

My arrayList is in a separate class, 
in my Main Activty I create an instance of that class and remove a value from the array.
I exit the Main Activity and return the value  re-appears.

My Question is how can I can some kind of static instance of the array class???

```
 //ArrayClass
 public class ArrayClass {

 public final static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

 public ArrayClass() {
    words.add("WORD");
    words.add("WORD");
    words.add("WORD");
 }

 //Main Class
 ArrayClass wordc = new ArrayClass();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
      wordc.removeWord(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orest is correct you do want a singleton pattern, but remember when you access the class's methods you always need to use the getInstance() method.

For example a method within the Class:

```
public String getWord(index i) {
     .......
}
```

Should be called statically as follows

```
ArrayClass.getInstance().getWord(i);
```

NOT like this

```
wordc.getWord(i);
```

This guarantees that there is one and only one instance (thus the singleton)

Answer (score 1):

I might be confused on what you are doing but to access the `static Array` you don't want to create an instance of the class. Everytime you do that you are running the constructor which, in the example code, populates your `static Array` each time with 3 values.

I don't see exactly what you are trying to accomplish so maybe you could explain that a little better but I'm guessing this really isn't what you want your constructor doing. I think you want to access the `Array` itself statically

```
 //Main Class
 ArrayClass wordc = new ArrayClass(); 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
      wordc.removeWord(0);  //don't need this
      ArrayClass.words.remove(0);  // would remove the element at index 0
 }
```

But this still wouldn't solve your problem. You need a method inside your `ArrayClass` class that adds items to your `Array`. Doing it in your constructor will add these items each time you create a new instance of your class.

If this doesn't answer your question then maybe you can explain your assignment a little better.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I need to keep the state of the array trough out the life cycle of the application, so when I go back to the main the instance of the array is the same state as when I left...Thanks for the reply!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All those singleton answers are terrible. This isn't C++ folks, leave singletons where they belong. +1 for best response

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Singleton patter? You will have one static reference of ArrayClass and it's internal state won't be violated by activity lifecycle.

```
public class ArrayClass {
     private static ArrayClass instance;
     public static ArrayClass getInstance() {
         if(instance == null) instance = new ArrayClass();
         return instance;
     }
//...rest goes as is.
```